# How do I work out how many lists are in a list?

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

So if list:

```
 a = [[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]]
```

How do I can I get python to return the number of lists in list 'a'?

Comment: `len(a)` ...........

Comment: what's your expected output for `[[[1], 2], [3]]` ?

Comment: Best way to use recursion to get length

Answer (score 5):

The type of the items in a list doesn't matter; the number of items in the list is `len(a)`.

If there can be items other than lists in `a` and you want to find out how many lists there are, as opposed to the other kinds of items, try:

```
sum(isinstance(item, list) for item in a)
```

Comment: Perfect, looks very nice

Answer (score 0):

You can use [len](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#len) function to get count of number of elements in your `list` object.

And if you have multiple types of element in your list object, you can filter `list` type element using built-in [filter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) function.

```
>>> a = [[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]]
>>> len(filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, list), a))
5
```

Comment: But it will return all elements which are of type list and we can get len of those elements.

Comment: It will *convert* all items to type `list` and return any that are not empty. If items can't be converted to a list, you get an exception. The first argument to `filter` must be a function that returns a truthy value for items you want in the list. `list` is not such a function and treating it as such is not going to get you the result you want.

Comment: I think you mean `filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, list), a)`

Comment: @kindall Thanks for youe better explanation.

Comment: @achampion Thanks. I thought it was just checking type by using list in filter but it was doing type conversion.